# jQuery toggle on the element inserted through execComand insertHTML

Tags: jquery, toggle, inserthtml

jQuery toggle doesn't work on the elements inserted in the div through execComand insertHTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#paste").click(function() {
       document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<div class='foobar'><p class='foo'>Spoiler</p><p class='bar'>" + window.getSelection().getRangeAt() + "</p></div>"); 
    });

    $(".foo").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggle();  
        })
    });
});

</script>
<style>

.content {
    widt:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.foo {
    border:1px solid #000;
    cursor:pointer;
} 

.bar {
   border:1px solid #000; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="paste">Spoiler</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra sapien diam, id ornare eros pulvinar quis. Nam volutpat consequat tellus nec gravida. Proin vestibulum nisl a adipiscing semper. Sed bibendum tortor ligula, ac ultricies nulla bibendum vitae. Morbi a leo tortor. Vestibulum tincidunt placerat erat, eu vulputate nisi elementum quis. Quisque ac odio in massa hendrerit aliquam ut a diam. Pellentesque nunc nibh, fringilla nec lectus vel, dictum tincidunt arcu.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Here's demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Slev7n/YDvSe/3/)

Comment: And what special reason is there to use `execCommand`?

Comment: I found the solution, event listener listens to the elements that were initialy in the dom but not those inserted later. So the solution is to unbind listener and bind again

http://jsfiddle.net/YDvSe/4/

Comment: Answer you own question then if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#paste").click(function() {
       document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<div class='foobar'><p class='foo'>Spoiler</p><p class='bar'>" + window.getSelection().getRangeAt() + "</p></div>");
    $(".foo").unbind();
    $(".foo").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggle();  
        })
    });

    });
});

</script>
<style>

.content {
    widt:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.foo {
    border:1px solid #000;
    cursor:pointer;
} 

.bar {
   border:1px solid #000; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="paste">Spoiler</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra sapien diam, id ornare eros pulvinar quis. Nam volutpat consequat tellus nec gravida. Proin vestibulum nisl a adipiscing semper. Sed bibendum tortor ligula, ac ultricies nulla bibendum vitae. Morbi a leo tortor. Vestibulum tincidunt placerat erat, eu vulputate nisi elementum quis. Quisque ac odio in massa hendrerit aliquam ut a diam. Pellentesque nunc nibh, fringilla nec lectus vel, dictum tincidunt arcu.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I found the solution, event listener listens to the elements that were initialy in the dom but not those inserted later. So the solution is to unbind listener and bind again http://jsfiddle.net/YDvSe/4/